# How to have less tired finger muscles when using Blender?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, mouse

As an old 3ds max user, I realized that Blender is tiring my finger muscles more. Why?

I am pressing my right hand finger to the mouse button AND with my left hand finger, I am pressing to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, for zooming in and out. Ok.
But when I want to pan, I have to raise my right hand finger and press again to mouse button. During this, I have to release my left hand finger and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This is 2 active process.

What i want is this (like in 3dsMax):
I want to keep my right hand finger "pressed" (no releasing) during my left hand finger is pressing and releasing for zooming in and panning. This is 1 active process.

With this, I am just moving my left hand finger. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can use any (non conflicting) keymap you like in blender. There is an industry compatible keymap in 2.8+ have you tried this?

Comment: I would suggest more exercise and working on your hand muscles. Exercising and strengthening your muscles would have additional benefit for health in general and it would save time and effort worrying about things like this. Most people have muscles adequate for pressing mouse and keyboard keys without any additional exercise so it shouldn't take too much effort. This will also allow you to have a consistent keymap across all Blender areas and the ability to use it wherever you find it (when visiting a friend, for example, on their computer).

Comment: Consider mouse3 and mouse4 buttons (side buttons)